# using python how do you get rid of trailing spaces in text that was scraped from a website

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

i am scraping text from a website and I'm using the strip function in python to get rid of these newlines and trailing spaces and replace all commas with space. however it doesn't do anything

````
            # print(predesc[0].div.p)
            itemDesc = predesc[0].div.p.text
            # itemDesc= str(itemDesc).strip("\\t\\n")
            itemDesc.strip()
            itemDesc.strip("\t")
            itemDesc.strip("\n\n")
            itemDesc.replace(",","")











            print(repr(itemDesc))```
output is
"                        Shortcut the learning curve with an all-around board that''s catch-free and easy for boosting confidence anywhere you take it.\n\nSome riders just want to get straight to the fun part. Enjoy a no-fuss feel with the Burton Instigator, a board designed to help accelerate the learning curve and instigate a good time from your first moment on the mountain. The combination of a Flat Top™ bend and Cruise Control convex base keeps things friendly underfoot, creating a catch-free feel that maintains stability and control. The Channel® mounting system gives you the easiest, most adjustable setup with bindings from all major brands (not just Burton''s). "
````

Comment: `strip()` returns a new value...it doesn't change the original string. You need something like `itemDesc = itemDesc.strip()`.

Comment: Assign to a variable what you would like to remove the trailing spaces. Then print it out.

Comment: thank you i followed that it did get rid of the spaces but the \n\n is not being striped

Comment: The same way that you would get rid of trailing whitespace from any other data.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemDesc = itemDesc.replace('  ',' ').replace(',','').replace("''","'").replace("\n","").strip()
```